# Some users randomly not able to see contextual Gmail gadget

Tags: gmail-contextual-gadgets

We're the developer of this gadget, and it's been running for a few years. We have end customers reporting that the toolbar is disappearing for some users, and are also seeing this for some of our own users. The toolbar is enabled in all cases for those users.

The gadget definition is at:

https://console.intellisync.net/service

and is working perfectly. We have end customers complaining - why is the toolbar disappearing?

The only possibly explanation that I can think of is that Gmail can't reach our servers for some users? However, we have some users within an organisation able to access the gadget, and some not, quite randomly. All users have the gadget enabled though.

Comment: We asked Google for an update.  We got the following... -> Thanks for contacting me again. I've researched about this situation and so far our engineering team has not sent any update upon the issue you are facing.

Currently we don't have any time frame either for a resolution, however I've reported your account to the database of this issue and I expect as soon as there's updates for this issue, you will be notified automatically.

Thanks in advance for your comprehension, we know the impact of this type of issues and we are currently working to provide a solution as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it is a global problem on the Google side:
[Gmail contextual gadget broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38118756/gmail-contextual-gadget-broken)

We will wait and hope that they will fix it fast

Comment: Hi Roman, are you seeing this with other contextual gadgets also by any chance?

Comment: Yes. Contextual gadges now always working only for messages opened in new window.

Answer (score 1):

I received an E-Mail from Google yesterday (wednesday):
"We have already identified the potential culprit and the fix for it is planned to go live this Friday."

Friday is 2016-08-07

Hopefully it starts working again next week.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a global issue.

Workaround for the user is to open the Message in a new Window

[image]

---

This is fixed today Saturday for our instance

Comment: Thanks for the response PNC! Yes, this does seem to work, but it's a significant issue for Google - they really need to get this sorted ASAP (i'm assuming it's not just our contextual gadget).

Comment: I raised a ticket with Google and they said-> We have detected this issue recently, and we are currently investigating the cause, by now there's no resolution for it yet, but we have a workaround described below:

The workaround is to press "shift" and then click on the email. The email will be opened in a new window and then the gadgets are displayed.